# Gitlab ci run job only in merge_request not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project where many people collaborate and we have a short workflow that we want to test in each branch anytime that we pull to our forked branches and we want to test a longer test if we make a merge request into the "central" repository.

For now the short version of the test runs well, and where we want, it looks like this:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    # here the order matter!
    # does not run with changes in .md files
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA !~ /0{40}/'
      changes:
        - "{*[^.]md*,*.[^m]*,*.m,*.m[^d]*,*.md?*,*[^d]}"
    # does not run when creating tags
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    # does not run if branches start with test_
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /test_/
      when: never
    # it runs with any branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

stages:          
  - build
  - test
  - plot

....

analysis-test-job:
  stage: test
  script: 
     - source run_shorttest.sh

analysis-longtest-job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - source run_longtest.sh
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
```

this works fine in our personal and central repositories but the `analysis-longtest-job` does never run.

Just to make it clear, what I want is that the `analysis-longtest-job` runs only after we make a merge request to the master branch of the "central" repository and after it passes the short workflow in each branch.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Just to be sure, is your default branch named "master"? For information you can use the $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH variable as a placeholder for the default branch instead of explicitly use "master".

Comment: If you're checking $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master", then you are checking if its a merge request to master, and dont need the first line $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event". This won't solve anything but will be more succinct

Comment: Perhaps an issue with your use of single quotes? Try removing those, and also removing the '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && part since it isn't needed

Comment: @EricMORAND thanks, yeah my default branch is master, but I have tested without that part and still does not work

Comment: @samsupertaco I tried with and without the single quotes and does not do anything.

Comment: Forgive me if this also doesn't work, but consider trying parentheses as described here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/37574 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `workflow:rules:` is preventing merge request pipelines from running. Therefore, `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` can never be `merge_request_event` because such pipelines are excluded by `workflow:rules:` as you have them. Specifically, note that the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is only present on branch pipelines and is NOT present on merge request pipelines or tag pipelines. You'll only be able to use variables like `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` on merge request pipelines. See also: [common `if` clauses for `workflow:rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#common-if-clauses-for-workflowrules).

To fix this, make sure your `workflow:rules:` allows merge request pipelines.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    # ...
    # allow branch pipelines
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

    # allow merge request pipelines to run
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

If you don't want to use merge request pipelines and want to use branch pipelines only, you can condition a rule on whether an MR is open for the branch using the `CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` variable instead, which is available in branch pipelines. However, you cannot condition this on the target of the MR in a branch pipeline.

```yaml
analysis-longtest-job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
  # ...
```